# MySQL order rank as a column

Tags: mysql, ranking

I have a MySQL query that selects data from multiple tables and then orders the results based on some arbitrary criteria as below:

```
SELECT [columns] FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) as `matches`
    FROM [table1]
    JOIN [table2] USING (id)
    JOIN [table3] USING (id)
  WHERE [criteria]
  GROUP BY `id`
  ORDER BY `matches` DESC
) AS `grouped`
ORDER BY (
  (CASE WHEN [1st rank criteria] THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) +
  (CASE WHEN [2nd rank criteria] THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) +
  (CASE WHEN [3rd tank criteria] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
) DESC
LIMIT 100
```

This works fine, but my question is: **can I have the ranking score displayed as a column**? I've looked at trying to use variables, but I'm quite new to SQL so all this is a bit beyond me.

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but many thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [columns],
   (
     (CASE WHEN [1st rank criteria] THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) +
     (CASE WHEN [2nd rank criteria] THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) +
     (CASE WHEN [3rd tank criteria] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   ) AS MyRank

FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) as `matches`
    FROM [table1]
    JOIN [table2] USING (id)
    JOIN [table3] USING (id)
    WHERE [criteria]
    GROUP BY `id`
    ORDER BY `matches` DESC
) AS `grouped`
ORDER BY MyRank DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realise the `CASE`s could be placed in that order. Thanks so much for prompt and helpful reply!

Answer (score 2):

put it in the select

```
((CASE WHEN [1st rank criteria] THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) +
 (CASE WHEN [2nd rank criteria] THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) +
 (CASE WHEN [3rd tank criteria] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as ranking
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You're absolutely right. I appreciate your help.